# How to integrate $\int{e^{\sin x}(\frac{x\cos^2{x}-\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}}) dx}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm stuck with this problem, and even after numerous tries, I can't seem to solve it. Please help me with this:
$$\int{e^{\sin x}\biggl(\frac{x\cos^2{x}-\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}}\biggr) dx}$$

Also, I'm always doubtful about how to proceed with **indefinite integration problems which involve substitutions**. While I know that they have to be solved by comparing them to some standard forms, I feel like there's more to it.

Could you please tell me how I should proceed and what's the catch in such problems?

I'd like to state that I know that we try to simplify the expression by substituting with a larger expression's elemental change, i.e $df(x)$.

Comment: What makes you think this integral is solvable?

Comment: @Vasya literally my first comment on almost every indefinite integral question.

Comment: If we simplify the integral given, we get $\int xe^{\sin(x)} + ...$, which does not have an elementary antiderivative, making the entire integral unsolvable.

Comment: @Vasya I found it in a book.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma Are you sure you copied it correctly? Does the book confirm the existence of a solution?

Comment: @ChristopherMarley I'm sure I copied it correctly. The book confirms the solution to be $e^{\sin{x}}(x - \sec{x})$ which I don't think is correct.

Comment: Now that the expression seems not integrable, would it be okay if I switched the title to how to approach indefinite integration problems? I want to develop its problem solving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume that the answer in the book is correct and let us compare

$$I=\frac d {dx} \left(e^{\sin(x)}(x - \sec(x))\right) \qquad \text{to} \qquad J=e^{\sin (x)}\left(\frac{x\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\right)$$
So
$$I=e^{\sin (x)} (x \cos (x)-\tan (x) \sec (x))=e^{\sin (x)}\left(\frac{x\cos^\color{red}{3}(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\right)$$

One more typo in a textbook !

The problem should be
$$\int e^{\sin (x)}\left(\frac{x\cos^\color{red}{3}(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\right)\,dx$$

Try [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Esin(x)+(x+cos(x)%5E3-sin(x))%2Fcos(x)%5E2) to confirm.

**Edit**

Using series expansion around $x=0$
$$I=-\frac{4 x^3}{3}-\frac{4 x^4}{3}-\frac{17 x^5}{15}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$J=-\frac{5 x^3}{6}-\frac{5 x^4}{6}-\frac{37 x^5}{40}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ are "quite" different.